# How to check for the existence of a folder in a given relative path?

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, path

I am trying to see if a specific folder exists
as a sub folder in a certain path.

Assume a path given in a variable `InputPath`
and a relative path given `RelPath`. 
How can I write a block to look if a given folder name
(given by a variable `FolderName`) exists in that path?

In that path means that if I do `dir` in the path `InputPath\RelPath`,
I want to check if `FolderName` is one of the folders listed.

I know `dir /d` can list only directories,
but I don't know how to search that list.

To make an example by a batch file:

```
@echo off

SET INPUT_PATH="D:\SomeFolder\OtherFolder\RandomFolder\"
SET REL_PATH="..\FunnyFolder"
SET FOLDER_NAME="SearchMeFolder"

goto IsFolder

:IsFolder
SET CURR_PATH=%CD%
cd "%INPUT_PATH%\%REL_PATH%"
:: Need to fetch all sub folder and check for existence
:: If exist, set FOLDER_EXIST to True, else False
```

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @DavidPostill, I look at related questions and all of them are "How to..." in the context of a script. Moreover, Have you seen my record on other sites? Do you really think I need to see how to ask? Could you tell me what's not clear about the question?

Comment: Read my first comment. You haven't provided any attempt at all to solve it yourself.

Comment: Your record on other sites is irrelevant.

Comment: I wrote my try. I think it will be nice to have some credit and patience towards beginners. All related question are the same with no try at all.

Comment: (1) I know that we are inconsistent in this, but we prefer questions where the asker has *tried* to solve the problem themselves.  You haven’t done that; you’ve only shown us the prelude of an attempt. (2) The fact that you say `cd %INPUT_PATH%\REL_PATH` make me feel like you aren’t really trying.  If you ran that, I expect that you would get an error.

Comment: @Scott, I am really clueless about batch files. Hence I'm asking an assistance with such a simple task. Hence I'm wiring what I think I'd do like I'm in the CMD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch file programming is messy. 
I can’t find any one solution that works perfectly. 
But this three-pronged approach seems to work:

```
SET CURR_PATH=%CD%

:: Assume/anticipate failure
set "FOLDER_EXIST=False"

cd /d "%INPUT_PATH%\%REL_PATH%" 2> nul  &&  (
    if exist  %FOLDER_NAME%\    set "FOLDER_EXIST=True"
    if exist "%FOLDER_NAME%\"   set "FOLDER_EXIST=True"
    cd %FOLDER_NAME% 2> nul &&  set "FOLDER_EXIST=True"
)
cd /d %CURR_PATH%
echo FOLDER_EXIST = %FOLDER_EXIST%.
```

Note that the `if` statements
are testing the (candidate) folder name *followed by a* `\`. 
For example,

```
    if exist C:\Windows\debug
    if exist C:\Windows\debug\
```

and

```
    if exist C:\Windows\notepad.exe
```

should all succeed, but

```
    if exist C:\Windows\notepad.exe\
```

should fail, because  `C:\Windows\notepad.exe` is not a folder.

---

```
    if exist  %FOLDER_NAME%\    set "FOLDER_EXIST=True"
```

will fail if `%FOLDER_NAME%` contains space(s) and is not quoted;
e.g., `set "FOLDER_NAME=Program Files"`.

```
    if exist "%FOLDER_NAME%\"   set "FOLDER_EXIST=True"
```

will fail if `%FOLDER_NAME%` contains space(s) and ***is*** quoted;
e.g., `set FOLDER_NAME="Program Files"`. 
And

```
    cd %FOLDER_NAME% 2> nul &&  set "FOLDER_EXIST=True"
```

will fail if you don’t have permission to `cd` into `%FOLDER_NAME%`.

Answer (score 1):

One line version using operator `&&` or `||` if exist/not exist:

```bath
>nul 2>&1 pushd "%cd%\my_Folder" &&(popd & set "Bool=True")|| set "Bool=False"

set Bool & echo=%Bool%
```